# Counting points in concentric circle buffer zones of different sites in a map?

Tags: buffer, statistics, circle

I produce concentric circles of 200 and 500 m buffer zones to see water points within each buffer zones.

The buffer zones are created throughout my study area. How can I count the points found in each concentric buffer zones? How can I differentiate the points found within 200 and 500 m buffer zones separably?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the GIS software and version you are using. Even if you use a donut search feature (500m - 200m), you still need to handle the boundary condition of exactly 200 feet.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Your title and content disagree -- Are the larger buffers 500m or 5km?

Comment: Without knowing what software you are using, there are too many possible solutions to this to suggest one as better than others. The *simplest* one I know of is using ArcGIS's multiple ring buffer tool to generate non-overlapping ring buffers and then intersect/summary stats or spatial join as already suggested. If you already have the buffers and they overlap, they can be unioned to create distinct rings.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ArcMap, the Spatial Join tool with the One to One option will add summaries of the Points to the Buffer shapes if the Buffers are the Target.  You can set one of the Point fields to be a Count field.  Other fields can be summarized with Sum, Min, Max, Mean, etc values.  If you need a list of values use the Join option and change the output field setting to a Text field with 255 characters and set a delimiter character.

Given that buffers will most likely overlap all over your dataset, the easiest method is to get the summaries that include all of the overlaps.  You can then separate the 200 m buffers from the corresponding 500 m buffer (separate buffer operations).  Then you can join them on the common ID field and subtract the 200 m summary counts from the 500 m summary counts if you wish to avoid double counting the points.

Overlaps between buffers of separate original features won't be handled by the technique and the overlaps will be double (or more) counted.  It is up to you to decide how you want overlaps handled and as Vince said your options for creating different buffer shapes depend on your software and license level.